# How to do remove a projects artifacts from the local maven repo?

Tags: maven, maven-3

When running `mvn install` on a local multi module project it builds and install the projects artifacts into the local repo. `mvn clean` seems to clean up my project specific target directories.

What command do I use with maven to get it to uninstall my projects modules from the local repo? for example my projects outputs foo-0.1.jar and bar-0.2.jar I want those removed from my local repo without having to go in there and delete them myself.

Comment: Well, typically I just... delete them from the file system...

Comment: there are 17 of them for a single project running a script to delete them is annoying, so I would rather maven do that since it knows what is there.

Comment: If you project outputs foo-0.1.jar which is from maven point of view a release which will never be deleted from the local repository. So the first question: Why do you like to delete them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can purge artifacts from your local repository, but why do you like to do this? Apart from that you can do that via [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html):

This will purge all project- and dependency artifacts

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false
```

This can be influenced by supplemental command line arguments (see the documentation) for further details.

Comment: I have `mvn install`ed some artifacts. After running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, other projects that depend on that artifact still build. Where do they get that artifact from if it has been remove from local repo?

Comment: `dependency:purge-local-repository` will *not* remote the artifact specified by the current pom itself. It just 'reloads' all dependencies.

Answer (score 56):

```
mvn build-helper:remove-project-artifact
```

Comment: deletes only current project from repository! usage: navigate into project and run command

Answer (score 2):

Best is to implement a release strategy, i.e. as long as the artifacts under development appending the version with `SNAPSHOT`. Maven then automatically updates the artifacts in the local repository when you run install. Once you have completed the development you remove the *SNAPSHOT* and release the version (i.e. via deploy). If further development is required you could increase the version number and append it again with SNAPSHOT.

Comment: This is a particularly bad strategy which will prevent you from detecting cyclic dependencies or artifacts gone missing until it's way too late.

Comment: How so?  It sounds to me like MrsTang is proposing the use of standard maven versioning...use -SNAPSHOT in the version during development and then remove that when it's time to release.  Though I'm not sure it really solves the challenge the user is facing when downloading dependencies, I don't follow how using standard versioning prevents you from detecting cyclic dependencies or missing artifacts.