# How to remove jar file from local maven repository which was added with install:install-file?

Tags: maven

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=phonegap-1.1.0.jar -DgroupId?=phonegap -DartifactId?=phonegap -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I use above command to install local jar into maven local repo. Now I have got the dependency from maven repo. I want to remove this from local repo. How to clean it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do remove a projects artifacts from the local maven repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631882/how-to-do-remove-a-projects-artifacts-from-the-local-maven-repo)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

While there is a maven command you can execute to do this, it's easier to just **delete** the files manually from the repository.

Like this on windows `Documents and Settings\your username\.m2` or `$HOME/.m2` on Linux

Comment: I would delete only the `.m2/repository directory`. A coworker has deleted the .m2 directory before and it causes issues because on our project we have to modify the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Do note that with deleting the `.m2/repository` directory you will also be deleting all maven plugin files. Whereas using the `purge-local-repository` command you are deleting only dependencies.

Comment: The directory structure under `.m2/repository` is organized by Maven group ID, so you can just delete the subdirectory corresponding to the artifact you want to remove.

Comment: I just deleted the jar file like so 
rm -riv ./com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar

Answer (score 144):

Although deleting files manually works, there is an *official* way of removing dependencies *of your project* from your local (cache) repository and optionally re-resolving them from remote repositories.

The goal `purge-local-repository`, on the standard Maven dependency plugin, will remove the locally installed dependencies *of this project* from your cache.  Optionally, you may re-resolve them from the remote repositories at the same time.

***This should be used as part of a project phase*** because it applies to the dependencies for the containing project. Also transitive dependencies will be purged (locally) as well, by default.

If you want to explicitly remove a single artifact from the cache, use `purge-local-repository` with the `manualInclude` parameter.  For example, from the command line:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude="groupId:artifactId, ..."
```

The documentation implies that this does not remove transitive dependencies by default. If you are running with a non-standard cache location, or on multiple platforms, these are more reliable than deleting files "by hand".

The full documentation is in the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) spec.

*Note*: Older versions of the maven `dependency` plugin had a `manual-purge-local-repository` goal, which is now (version 2.8) implied by the use of `manualInclude`. The documentation for `manualIncludes` (with an `s`) should be read as well.

Comment: I don't believe that this works for `.jar`s that were not downloaded from maven central or some other repository. When I run this command it gets rid of all the `.jar`s that automatically downloaded, but when it gets to the `.jar`s that I manually installed, it outputs this error message:  


    `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:purge-local-repository (default-cli) on project alloy-generator: Failed to refresh project dependencies for: myartifact: required artifacts missing:
    [ERROR] manually-downloaded-and-installed.jar
    ...`

Comment: Actually, after I checked it, I realized that it does uninstall the `.jar`, but it still outputs an error. So for `.jar`s which have been manually installed, I would recommend manually deleting rather than using this method, because maven creates some weird files like `yourjar.jar.lastUpdated` and `yourjar.pom.lastUpdated` which you may need to manually delete anyway. But if maven managed all the dependencies automatically, this is a great way to uninstall the dependencies.

Comment: This approach also requires a maven project in order to run the command.  This doesn't appear to work if you ran the install command that the OP specified in the context of say a Gradle build.

Comment: You can even remove a complete group with: `dependency:purge-local-repository -Dinclude=de.slr -DresolutionFuzziness=groupId`

Answer (score 26):

At least on the current maven version you need to add the switch -DreResolve=false if you intend to remove the dependencies from your local repo without re-downloading them.

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false
```

removes the dependencies without downloading them again.

Answer (score 13):

Delete every things (jar, pom.xml, etc) under your local `~/.m2/repository/phonegap/1.1.0/` directory if you are using a linux OS.

Comment: When I remove the jar that way, it "re-downloads" the jar from the old folder. May be there are references that need to be removed as well.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem, went through all the suggestions above, but nothing worked.
Finally I deleted both .m2 and .ivy folder and it worked for me.