# where can I find maven repository for kafka?

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I want to try kafka 0.8 (as I understand it is already released). But where can I find the kafka maven repository.

And what additional repository url should I add?

I've found some blogs with

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.8.0</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0-SHA</version>
 </dependency>
```

but it is not works. I'm looking for proper maven dependency. Or should I checkout it from git and deploy in our internal artifactory?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/1356qq1fry/maven-integration-in-0-8) will help.

Comment: Especially this comment http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/1356qq1fry/maven-integration-in-0-8#20130507cbk3h24nhazgyyb85pmykcas48

Comment: Thanks, I can take kafka7 from conjars. But in general I probably got miss-understanding that kafka8 is released

Comment: The accepted answer provided by Cebence below is good not only because it provides an answer for this particular Kafka need but, in general, cleverly also answers the question of how to handle JAR dependencies that are needed, but which have not yet made it into the Maven repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since November 2013 official Kafka releases can be found on [public Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10), the latest version in March 2015 being `0.8.2.1`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you created the `not.released:kafka` artifact detailed below any more you can [remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358977) from the local repository.

---

*Original Answer*

Kafka is not released yet to a public Maven repository, but you can add it to your local Maven repository by hand with the [install-file command](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=not.released
    -DartifactId=kafka -Dversion=0.8.0 -Dfile=kafka.jar
```

The command line above expects `kafka.jar` file in the current working directory.
Once installed you can use it with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>not.released</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Once they release Kafka you can just change the dependency in your POMs and remove / uninstall this file from your local repository.

Comment: Kafka 0.8.0-beta1 is now available at maven.org.  groupId is org.apache.kafka, artifactId is kafka_2.9.2 (2.9.2 is the scala version, others are available), version is 0.8.0-beta1.

Comment: Since Kafka is published one should use the official Maven dependency. My answer is a general way of making Maven dependency from a library that doesn't have Maven support, it will work on any JAR.

Answer (score 6):

As of December 2013, Kafka 0.8 Final was released and is available under the following definition:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: seems to be a bad pom.xml file, has two <dependencies> tags (should be one)

Comment: can u be bit more specific?

Comment: sure, the pom.xml file is not a valid pom.xml according to: http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd . the <dependencies> tag has maxOccurs="1" and in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.9.2/0.8.0-beta1/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.0-beta1.pom it appears twice with the configuration split between the two tags. 
they should be united into a single <dependencies> tag

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is already answered, I think future readers might benefit from a complete simple example that works out of the box.  I put one together here > 
https://github.com/buildlackey/cep

Like the o.p., I have been fighting to find a Maven pom.xml recipe that will allow me to pull in an official version of Kafka from a public Maven repository.  I did manage to get my example working, but for now I have had to hack
 my dependencies so that the version of Kafka I use is pulled from a work-in-progress version of a 
storm-kafka integration project. I'm concerned the 'wip' versions below will be deprecated. 
Then this project will lose its dependencies and fail to build properly. Also, I 
really shouldn't be introducing storm for this simple Kafka example at this point in any case.

```
   
        storm
        storm
        0.9.0-wip17
    
    
        storm
        storm-core
        0.9.0-wip17
    
    
        storm
        storm-kafka
        0.9.0-wip16a-scala292
```

If someone could provide me with a patch for 'the right way' to do this with Maven I will update my project accordingly.... Hopefully it will serve as a useful resource for other beginning Kafka developers.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka and choose from the list kafka repository matching to your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the realease version here:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.kafka%22

Answer (score -1):

Here is another clue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sksamuel.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```