# How to add external jar library with Maven, with the possibility of following full(with external jar inside) packaging?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

I use Maven and have external library(soot). I want to add this library to my project with Maven, and then package into 1 uber jar.

1)To add library, i can use local repo([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320920/3268311)).

2)To get a jar with dependencies, i can use shade-plugin or other.

But together it isn't work, because on first step dependency have scope , and this dependency will not be added to uber jar.

I understand that i can do mvn install, but it will work only on my machine.

Is it possible to achieve my initial goal?

Comment: what kind of scope?? have you tried https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html ?

Comment: mvn install works fine, but i need to do it on every computer

Comment: and what scope do you use?? it should work fine

Comment: and maybe check this question in case you have similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015685/maven-3-does-not-update-snapshot-dependency-from-local-repository

Comment: It works. In this solution i should install this file on every computer(where i will run my programm). I want to modify something that can be under vcs(pom.xml or another files in my project).

Comment: but dummy question: what's wrong with in-project local repo (as from your example)?

Comment: As i understand dependency from local repository has scope <system>. Am i wrong?

Comment: not at all, local repository is as any other. system scope has complete different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest solution for you would be to use your local (company?) repository like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/).

However if it is not possible, you can use local in-project repository (as from your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project/11320920#11320920)) and keep it in your vcs.

```xml
<repository>
    <id>in-project</id>
    <name>In Project Repo</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
</repository>
```

The only trick is how to get artifacts (jars) to that local repository:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=fooLib.jar  -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=fooLib -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file://pathTo/libRepo -DrepositoryId=in-project
```

And you just use it as any other dependency

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>fooLib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Definitely don't use `system` [scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies), since such dependencies are expected to be found in system and therefore are not bundled with JAR.