# How to remove package with maven

Tags: java, maven, package

In my project dependency, I have a jar file and I want to delete some packages from being compiled,

Usually, I use maven-shade-plugin to relocate, but now I want to totally remove the package.

Comment: Q: Are you saying that you have some .java *SOURCE* files, in a package subdirectory in your project, and you want to prevent the "javac" Maven target from building all the files in that package?  If so, you should be able to use `<excludes>`.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262794/maven-exclude-folder-from-build

Comment: You can check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358977/5155885