# Maven tool of Java, how to using mvn uninstall package?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Java, mvn tool, how to using mvn uninstall package? Have some plugin, tool, shell script and  command method?

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve? What do you want to "uninstall"?

Comment: Could please explain more in detail what you like to achieve?

Comment: like pip of python, `pip uninstall pandas`, like this command or operator.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to uninstall/remove any artifact downloaded by maven just go to your `~/.m2/repository` directory, where all installed artifacts are stored and delete that one which you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning `mvn` and in the [Getting Started](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#how-do-i-create-a-jar-and-install-it-in-my-local-repository) guide, I am around about `mvn install`.

It looks like `mvn` doesn't provide an [uninstaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninstaller) out of the box (though it does have `mvn clean`, that does something else, possibly a simultaneous invention of [automake clean](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html)).

So for me, the options became:

(A) Read what `mvn install` did:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Installing /home/peter/Projects/my-app/target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/peter/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/peter/Projects/my-app/pom.xml to /home/peter/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

So I can manually reverse it (for macOS/Linux, Windows is left as an exercise for the interested reader):

```
cd ~/.m2/repository
cd com
rm -rf mycompany
```

As the example project only has [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit4/) as a test dependency, it's unclear to me how non-test dependencies are installed or uninstalled yet.

(B) Write a script to reverse (A), in the spirit of the [Philosophy of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/background/philosophy-of-maven.html), it looks like in practice this means [writing a plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugins.html)... so consider how it's been done in other Apache Projects [like `sling:uninstall`](https://sling.apache.org/components/sling-maven-plugin/uninstall-mojo.html).

(C) As the [`.m2` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63139745/1101109) is where Maven stores dependencies, go all out and delete the `.m2` repo, as it can be repopulated via the commands given in [Getting Started](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#how-do-i-create-a-jar-and-install-it-in-my-local-repository) to that point, so: `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository`

(D) Get someone else's plugin to see if it does the work for me (via [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870051/1101109)):

```
mvn build-helper:remove-project-artifact
```

Though this actually does quite a lot of work which I don't understand yet and so makes me nervous ([possible docs?](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/remove-project-artifact-mojo.html)), plus it doesn't actually delete the now empty `~/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app` directory:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'blocked' (position: START_TAG seen ...</url>\n      <blocked>... @164:16)  @ /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml, line 164, column 16
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (915 B at 5.3 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/3.5.0/build-helper-maven-plugin-3.5.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/3.5.0/build-helper-maven-plugin-3.5.0.pom (7.4 kB at 255 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/mojo-parent/77/mojo-parent-77.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/mojo-parent/77/mojo-parent-77.pom (36 kB at 844 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.10.0/junit-bom-5.10.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.10.0/junit-bom-5.10.0.pom (5.6 kB at 353 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/3.5.0/build-helper-maven-plugin-3.5.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin/3.5.0/build-helper-maven-plugin-3.5.0.jar (71 kB at 1.8 MB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany.app:my-app >----------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.5.0:remove-project-artifact (default-cli) @ my-app ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.pom (8.7 kB at 433 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/13/plexus-13.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/13/plexus-13.pom (27 kB at 1.4 MB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.9.3/junit-bom-5.9.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.9.3/junit-bom-5.9.3.pom (5.6 kB at 296 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/3.1.0/file-management-3.1.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/3.1.0/file-management-3.1.0.pom (4.5 kB at 214 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/36/maven-shared-components-36.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/36/maven-shared-components-36.pom (4.9 kB at 233 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.pom (2.7 kB at 196 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.36/slf4j-parent-1.7.36.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.36/slf4j-parent-1.7.36.pom (14 kB at 641 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/3.1.0/file-management-3.1.0.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.jar (192 kB at 3.5 MB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar (41 kB at 643 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/3.1.0/file-management-3.1.0.jar (36 kB at 404 kB/s)
[INFO] /home/peter/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app/my-app removed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.056 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-25T11:10:02+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(E) Abandon this for now, e.g. choose not to mind the clutter and I don't need the space.

P.S. I get the [timsort in Java is broken feeling](http://envisage-project.eu/proving-android-java-and-python-sorting-algorithm-is-broken-and-how-to-fix-it/#sec4). Also, it's worth considering: [image: Is it worth the time?]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the dependency from your `pom.xml`, maven should take care of the rest.

I really struggled with this because I had an upstream dependency that included the dependency I was trying to remove, so even `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` didn't help - in that case, it might be worth trying to configure dependency exclusions (also in the `pom.xml` file).