# what is .m2 folder, how can I configure it if I have two repos with two different projects

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using maven for my project, but I have two projects with different set of dependencies. One project requires a ton of dependencies while the other requires only a few. So, when I do a maven build all the unnecessary dependencies are also downloaded because the settings.xml is pointing to the same repository every time.
How do I let the maven know to use a different repo?

Comment: Why do you want different repository directories for different projects? You can just use the same one.

Comment: @jfabianmeier I already have a project in my local and I have imported a new different project  from github, when I try to build the new one, the dependencies are being downloaded or referred from .m2(which is configured for my local project), now is there a possibility of creating another .m2 or how does it work if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: You can just use the same `.m2/repository` for all the projects on your computer.

Comment: Understood, one last thing will .m2 contain artifacts developed by me as dependencies. PS: documentation is quite difficult to follow

Comment: If you build an artifact with `mvn clean install`, it will go to `.m2/repository`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.m2` folder is the default folder used by maven to store its:

- `settings.xml` file which specifies properties, like the central repository to download your dependencies, the location of the so-called `localRepository`
- by default, the `localRepository` in which maven stores all the dependencies your project might need to run.

Basically, when you build a Java application, the JDK only is not enough. You might need 3rd part libraries to help during the development. For instance:

- A lib to read CSV file
- A lib to do unit tests
- A lib to indicate weather ?

Anyway, without Maven, you'd be forced to download everything onto your computer, and indicate manually to your Java apps where to find those dependencies.
That is the role of maven. It is a dependency management tool, that centralize in a single place the dependencies your project has, and give you in a standard way access to those librairies, in order to make you more efficient.

By default, maven fetches the dependencies from this website: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

In term of efficiency, it is better to share the same localRepository across your projects, as it avoids maven from downloading the same dependencies again... I don't even know if there is a way, and if not, that is for a good reason: It is useless to have different local Repository in your computer

Comment: recently I have added a different local repo in .m2, by placing a new copy of settings.xml. The new_settings.xml has a tag called <localRepository>C:\Users\my_name\.m2\different_repository</localRepository>. when I update maven settings in eclipse a new repo is created. I find a diff repo to be useful cuz, the unwanted libs won't be downloaded for a diff project and there won't be a chance of conflict.